# React Native measure networking bandwidth usage

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How can I measure the network bandwidth usage for a React Native application (iOS and Android versions) over a period without using the performance monitoring tool build in React Native?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Android, you can attach a performance monitor from Android Studio to the running emulator or device and observe network usage in the performance monitor tab. If you're using IOS, XCode should automatically attach a performance monitor to the active emulator/device. From there, you can observe network usage.

If you'd like to observe network usage granularly, you can open the developer menu and tapping on the "Toggle Inspector". That should toggle the inspector tab alongside a "Network" tab that lets you see any incoming/outgoing network requests.

A combination of this and the Android Studio/XCode should let you eye-ball network activity without a build tool.

Comment: I forgot to specify. I want to measure the network usage for a deployed app.

Comment: You can get a performance monitor app from the google play store that has "Network Activity" monitor. If you want more granularity, use WireShark from a PC and capture network requests from there. It really depends on how much details you want to see.